# sed to remove text if it exists between first space and first number

Tags: text-processing

I have a file that looks like this:

```
abuse@verizon.net abuse@verizon.net 100.0.9.181
abuse@verizon.net abuse@verizon.net 100.1.147.27
abuse@verizon.net abuse@verizon.net 100.32.40.7
abuse@universal.net.id abuse@universal.net.id abuse@universal.net.id 101.0.7.77
abuse@republictelecom.com.sg 101.100.177.191
abuse@cnc-noc.net abuse@cnc-noc.net abuse@cnc-noc.net 101.17.155.18
abuse@telstra.net 101.174.11.146
abuse@telstra.net 101.174.2.218
```

I'd like to use `sed` (or `awk`) to manipulate the file so that everything after the first space and up to (but not including the space before) the first occurrence of a number is removed. So the above would end up looking like this:

```
abuse@verizon.net 100.0.9.181
abuse@verizon.net 100.1.147.27
abuse@verizon.net 100.32.40.7
abuse@universal.net.id 101.0.7.77
abuse@republictelecom.com.sg 101.100.177.191
abuse@cnc-noc.net 101.17.155.18
abuse@telstra.net 101.174.11.146
abuse@telstra.net 101.174.2.218
```

I've tried:

```
sed  '/\s.*$\([0-9]\)/\1/g' <filename>
sed  '/\s.*$/,/0-9/p' <filename>
sed  '/\s.*$/,/\(\[0-9\]\)/p' <filename>
```

and many other combinations of examples I've found on the Web. I think the problem may be that sometimes the line is already as I want it; other times there are two or more extra email addresses between the first email address and the ip address.

Edit: I will always want the first email address occurring on a line (sometimes there is only one; other times there are more than one), and everything else on the line removed up until the space before the IP address at the end. I need to keep a space between the email address and the IP address. If the line contains only one email address and the IP address, I'd like to leave it alone.

Can anyone (please) help?

Comment: (Thank you for fixing my post Byte Commander...this is the first time I've used this.)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. You say you don't want to include numbers but your desired output shows numbers as well. Also, will your files always be like that? Will you always want the 2nd and last fields?

Comment: Also, can we just say that you want the last occurence of an email address followed by an IP on each line? Anything wrong with this wording?

Comment: kos, that would work as well.

Comment: terdon, I misworded my original question. Thank you for catching that. I've fixed it and hopefully clarified what I'd like to do. The files will always be in this format, where there is one or more email addresses on a line, followed by a single IP address.

Comment: OK, so is Kos right? Do you simply always want the last 2 fields? In the cases where there are multiple emails do you always want the 1nd email or always want the last email?

Comment: Yep, sorry but it's still not clear, I asked you if the criterium could be reworded for simplicity to "print only the *last* occurence of an email address followed by an IP address on each line" and you said that would work as well, but in the question you now edited "I will always want the *first* email address occurring on a line", so what do you need exactly?

Comment: Hi kos, either way would've worked - as long as I end up with a single email address followed by a space and then a single IP address. The email addresses are always the same on each line - it's just that sometimes there is just one (in which case the line is fine the way it is), other times there are two or three as in the example. It doesn't matter which address it uses as they are always the same on any given line, but there can't be more than one once the awk is run against the "misformatted" original file. Hope that helps to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the output you show (and not the one you describe), you can simply print the 1st and the last fields using `awk`:

```
awk '{print $1,$NF}' file
```

Or `perl`:

```
perl -lane 'print "$F[0] $F[$#F]"' file
```

Comment: Thank you terdon. Will this also work if there are three or four occurrences of the email address before the IP address? And will it retain the ones that are already properly formatted?

Thanks, Sam

Comment: Actually I answered my own question... This seems to work. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @samgoober Yes, it will work for an arbitrary number of email addresses as long as i) the 2nd field is the email you want and ii) the last field is the IP you want.

Comment: I was wondering how to accept the solution. I worked on this for about three hours, and you answered it in about three minutes. I'm very grateful to you for your help. (I did change it to where it pulls the first email address since there will always be at least one but not always two, but wouldn't have gotten that far without your help.) Thank you again!

Comment: @kos eek! You're right, I missed that and so did the OP, probably. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @samgoober I had a bug in the first version, please see the update.

Comment: Hi terdon, yeah, I did catch that and changed it to $1. Appreciate you following up though. Looking forward to the day I know enough about this stuff to be able to help people.... :)